# undefined local variable or method `user' for main:Object (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, factory-bot

If i run rspec spec in terminal I will see this error:

```
3:in `<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `user' for main:Object (NameError)
from /home/marketa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
from /home/marketa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
from /home/marketa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /home/marketa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
from /home/marketa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1327:in `block in load_spec_files'
from /home/marketa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1325:in `each'
from /home/marketa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1325:in `load_spec_files'
from /home/marketa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:102:in `setup'
from /home/marketa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:88:in `run'
from /home/marketa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:73:in `run'
from /home/marketa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:41:in `invoke'
from /home/marketa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/marketa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
from /home/marketa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
from /home/marketa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /home/marketa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

My app/models/user.rb looks like this:

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable

    belongs_to :contact, :foreign_key => "contact_id", dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact

    has_many :advertisements
    has_many :reviews

    #accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact
    #accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact>>>>>>> e29ade655eb7ee8f553f049b9fbb505581246758
    after_create :welcomer
    before_create :set_default_role

    validates :email, presence: true

    ROLES = %w[admin user]
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

     def get_replies_where_advertisement(advertisement, user)
    Reply.where("advertisement_id = ? OR receiver = ?", advertisement.id, user.id).order(created_at: :DESC)


    end


    def get_replies_user(reply)
    user = User.find_by(:id => reply.user_id)

  end

  private
  def welcomer
    UserMailer.welcome_email(self)
  end

  def set_default_role
    if self.role.blank?
        self.role = 'user'
    end
  end

end
```

My spec/models/user_spec.rb looks like this:

```
require  'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe user, type: :model do
describe "relation" do
    it {should has_many :advertisements}
    it {should has_many :reviews}
    it {should belongs_to(:contact).dependent(:destroy)}
end

describe "validation" do
    it {should validate_presence_of :email}
end
end
```

And my spec/factories/user.rb looks like this

```
require 'faker'

FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :user do

    end
end
```

Please help, thanks

Comment: You need the class name, i.e. `RSpec.describe User`, case is important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have

```
Rspec.describe User, type: :model do
  #code
```

Comment: @MarkétaGlatzová you wrote you had `Rspec.desribe user`.